# How To Handle If Response Is nil, in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, httpresponse

All,
How to handle if the response is nil.
if response do have any network issue it provided me string format.

```
 if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // print response .
 }
    //on successfully response, which provided dictionary, 
    //check for key success which do have true or false.
 else if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue] == true) {
    // on true print response data.
 }
    //on success response, with failure message which is false.
 else if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue] == false) {
    // handle error on success is false.
 }
```

Here my question comes,if make response to nil 
`response = nil`; 
how to handle if response is nil?  and satisfy the above the conditions also.

since manually i set response data is nil.

`id response = nil;` it trigger the below condition also.

```
else if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue] == false) {
// handle error on success is false.
}
```

@All Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check these conditions [[response objectForKey:@"success"] after checking response != nil.

Comment: Also check headers. In cases like server returns HTML string, Header can help to see error status and etc...

Comment: @iOSWeblineindia  I am checking if server return HTML string also.  But when response is  nil it's give me  a crash Exc_Bad_Access(code=1, address=0x3c)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
    // Handle you error
    }else{
// handle your logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dictResults = [parse objectWithString:[[request responseString]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] error:nil];

 if (dictResults==nil)
{
   NSLog(@"%@",dictResults);
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"%@",dictResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this will help you.

```
if(response != nil){

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // print response .
    }
    //on successfully response, which provided dictionary, 
check for key success which do have true or false.
    else if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue] == true) {
    // on true print response data.
    }

    //on success response, with failure message which is false.
    else if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue] == false) {
    // handle error on success is false.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, **nil** is defined as a value called **__DARWIN_NULL**, which essentially evaluates to **0** or **false** in if-statements. Therefore, writing **if (x == nil)** is the same as writing **if (!x)** and writing if **(x != nil)** is equal to **if (x)** (since comparing to false creates a negation, and comparing to true keeps the condition the same).

You can write your code either way, and it really depends on which you think is more readable. I find **if (x)** to make more sense, but it depends on your style.

It's like comparing **if (someCondition == true)** versus **if (someCondition)**.
It all depends on you, and who's going to be reading the code.

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, any condition that evaluates to a value other than 0 is considered to be true, and therefore, if someCondition in the example above were to evaluate to an integer value of, say, -1, comparing it to true would result in false, and the if-statement would not be evaluated. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c

```
    if (response == nil) 
    {
        NSLog (@"means value is missing!");
    }
    else if ([response boolValue] == YES)
    {
        NSLog (@"means value is YES");
    }
    else if ([response boolValue] == NO)
    {
        NSLog (@"means value is NO");
    }
```

objectForKey will return nil if a key doesn't exist

```
  Symbol    Value            Meaning
  =======   =============   =========================================
   NULL     (void *)0       literal null value for C pointers
   nil      (id)0           literal null value for Objective-C objects
   Nil      (Class)0        literal null value for Objective-C classes
  NSNull    [NSNull null]   singleton object used to represent null


  NSString *strOP = [results objectForKeyOrNil:@"OP"];

 - (id)objectForKeyOrNil:(id)key {
     id val = [self objectForKey:key];
     if ([val isEqual:[NSNull null]] || val==nil) {
         return nil;
     }

     return val;
 }
```